# How to send a RestTemplate/Request inside a Zuul Filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have a core MS that is just a passthrough and add headers to all incoming request. And I was trying to call a Validate Session API inside a Zuul Filter so that it would call this first before adding the headers on all request, and if this errors out, the transaction will not proceed. However, it seems that there's no way I could send a basic rest template request inside the filter. What am I doing wrong then or did I miss something else?. Heres the code snippet.

```
public class WebFilter extends ZuulFilter {

 @Override
    public String filterType() {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        restTemplate.getForEntity(this.loginService.validateCache(hostUrl,validateSessionUrl, ctx.getRequest().getParameter("SessionId")).toUriString(),String.class

         ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("clientid", clientId);
        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("clientsecret", clientSecret);
        return "pre";
    }
}
```

And the resttemplate part gives the ff. error. Removing that however will make the app work, however I need that rest template to call the Validate API. Am I supposed to place this somewhere else, or something else?

> 2019-12-20 10:11:50.337 ERROR 4224 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start embedded container; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   com.bdo.fintech.web.core.Application.main(Application.java:26)
>   ~[classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:116)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:83)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:530)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    ... 8 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulConfiguration$ZuulFilterConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'filters': Error
>   creating bean with name 'webFilter' defined in
>   com.bdo.fintech.web.core.Application: Bean instantiation via factory
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.bdo.fintech.web.core.WebFilter]: Factory method
>   'webFilter' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'webFilter' defined in
>   com.bdo.fintech.web.core.Application: Bean instantiation via factory
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.bdo.fintech.web.core.WebFilter]: Factory method
>   'webFilter' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:233)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:181)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:162)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:79)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:241)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:228)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   ~[na:na]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'webFilter' defined in
>   com.bdo.fintech.web.core.Application: Bean instantiation via factory
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.bdo.fintech.web.core.WebFilter]: Factory method
>   'webFilter' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1049)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   ... 35 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.bdo.fintech.web.core.WebFilter]: Factory method
>   'webFilter' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   ... 49 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null   at
>   com.bdo.fintech.web.core.WebFilter.filterType(WebFilter.java:89)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.disablePropertyName(ZuulFilter.java:89)
>   ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]  at
>   com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.(ZuulFilter.java:54)
>   ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]  at
>   com.bdo.fintech.web.core.WebFilter.(WebFilter.java:34)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.bdo.fintech.web.core.Application.webFilter(Application.java:31)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.bdo.fintech.web.core.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c625e823.CGLIB$webFilter$0()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.bdo.fintech.web.core.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c625e823$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2090f8d.invoke()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   com.bdo.fintech.web.core.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c625e823.webFilter()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]   ... 50 common frames
>   omitted
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Can you paste the entire WebFilter.java file? I am more concerned at what you are doing at line WebFilter.java line#89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by moving the RestTemplate inside a condition that determines whether if request is null or not

```
if(ctx.getRequest() != null) {
 // Put Rest template code here
} else {
// Some more code that will handle when the request is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override run() method for your filter logic

```java
    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

...

        return null;
    }
```

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#zuul-developer-guide-sample-pre-filter